# How to retrieve the latest engagements from hubspot using Engagements API

Tags: javascript, salesforce, crm, hubspot

I am trying to retrieve all engagements using hubspot engagements api. `https://api.hubapi.com/engagements/v1/engagements/paged?hapikey=xxxxxx`

As of today which is Dec 27, I am getting engagements till Nov 30. Is there a way to get the latest results.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is happening because of the pagination. In a single response up to 250 records will be returned. So, if you have more than that the rest will be in another page for which you will have to make another request.

In your response check if "hasMore" is true, if it is that means there are more engagements than what you see. You can use "offset" to get the rest of the data.

Here's the [link to documentation](https://legacydocs.hubspot.com/docs/methods/engagements/get-all-engagements) for further info.